# Prism map on point data in Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to generate a prism map on point data? I have a certain time duration/delay on each point. All I want is to generate a KML file giving (lat, lon, time) on each point and view that in Google Earth on a certain scale. I have found [this example](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2008/05/animated-prism-map-in-google-earth.html) but it's on polygon data not only point data.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't an [extruded point placemark](http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Point_Placemarks/Point_Placemarks.Extruded.kml) do ?

Answer (score 0):

If extruded point placemarks are not what you want, you could generate a small polygon for each point (a square or circle of a certain scale correct radius) and combine that using the example on polygons you already found.